# why i can't take a screen with LG nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, screenshots

I'm trying to take a screenshot on my Nexus 5 phone following the obvious [instructions](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2811098?hl=en), which instruct me to press both the down button and the power button at the same time.. nothing happens.

I remember in my previous S3 phone there was some some setting that had to be turned on to enable swiping gestures to take a screenshot.. but i couldn't find anything of that sort with the nexus 5.. any ideas?

Comment: Power+VolumeDown (pressed at exactly the same time) has always worked for me on my Nexus 5 without changing any settings.

Comment: Mmm.. Could my phone be defective then?

Comment: Always worked for me as well. Try holding for about 5 secs and see if that changed. Might be a delay issue?

Comment: Ah it worked.. The idea is to press and hold for a bit.. It isn't just a tap lol

Comment: Another good link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot#Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android's hotkey to take screenshots is Vol Down and Power pressed simultaneously for about 3 seconds.

The delay is there to prevent accidental presses.

( Samsung phones hotkey is the Power and Home button )

Answer (score 1):

You're right that is the way the image should be captured and saved in the Folder **Screenshots**. But sadly, some of the ROM manufactures remove this feature from the ROM, don't know why, but yes they do so and the user isn't able to use this feature.

I have a phone, Qmobile Noir A8 and on this phone I was able to capture the screenshot through the very same process and this was the very first phone I noticed Android OS has this feature too.

But then I installed a new Custom ROM on it.

http://www.incpak.com/tech/qmobile-noir-a8-jellybean-4-2-2-download/ (Link for the ROM)

And til then, I am not able to capture the screen shot using these buttons.

So the ROM you're using might not have this functionality or might have been overriden by some other function. If you still can't figure it out, you can try contacting LG for this issue. They would guide you in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications (eg: mobile banking solutions) are blocking the possibility to take screenshot for security reasons.

Comment: While the information you claim may be true, can you provide source(s) or at least link to such an app with this info mentioned there?

Answer (score -1):

I find a way to do it with custom ROM bug.

Root -> es file explorer
I got the way : /sdcard/Pictures/

You should see a Screenshot folder

Add a new Screenshot folder 'Screenshots' named.

Else, press sound down and power.

Now, the screenshot will eraze the problem with the same problem in the folder screeshot and your news S.S. will come in the Screenshots folder.

It works.
Sun(fr)
:)